# Python: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

Tags: python, typeerror, morse-code

Trying to convert morse code input back into English.

```
morse_code = { 'A' : ".- ",
               'B' : "-... ", 
               'C' : "-.-. ",
               'D' : "-.. ",
               'E' : ". ", 
               'F' : "..-. ",
               'G' : "--. ",
               'H' : ".... ", 
               'I' : ".. ",
               'J' : ".--- ",
               'K' : "-.- ", 
               'L' : ".-.. ",
               'M' : "-- ",
               'N' : "-. ", 
               'O' : "--- ",
               'P' : ".--. ",
               'Q' : "--.- ", 
               'R' : ".-. ",
               'S' : "... ",
               'T' : "- ", 
               'U' : "..- ",
               'V' : "...- ",
               'W' : ".-- ", 
               'X' : "-..- ",
               'Y' : "-.-- ",
               'Z' : "--.. ",
               '0' : "----- ",
               '1' : ".---- ",
               '2' : "..--- ",
               '3' : "...-- ", 
               '4' : "....- ",
               '5' : "..... ",
               '6' : "-.... ", 
               '7' : "--... ",
               '8' : "---.. ",
               '9' : "----. ", 
               ' ' : "  "
}

# reverse key
morse_code_reverse = {value:key for key,value in morse_code.items()}
```

The function trying to convert morse code input back into English

```
def revert_morse_code_dictionary(text):
    return ''.join(morse_code_reverse.get(i) for i in text.split())
```

main

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cont = True
    while cont:
        text = input("Please enter a line of morse code text. Enter an empty line to stop.\n")
        print(revert_morse_code_dictionary(text))
        if text != "":
            print(decode_morse(text))
        else:
            cont = False
```

Why does this keep returning this error? When the input is along the lines of

```
-.-. .- -. -.-- --- ..- .-. . .- -.. -- .
```

```
in revert_morse_code_dictionary
    return ''.join(morse_code_reverse.get(i) for i in text.split())
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

Comment: When you call `morse_code_reverse.get(i)` and `i` is not a key in `morse_code_reverse`, it returns None. If you used `morse_code_reverse[i]` instead, you'd get a KeyError which would tell you the key that is causing the problem. Using `get` here just makes your code harder to debug.

Comment: All of your Morse code strings end in a space.  Since `split` removes all spaces, none of the values in your split string will be present in the reverse dictionary.  You need to remove all of the spaces from the dictionary.

Comment: @TomKarzes I was incredibly  slow in writin my answer from my phone, so I didn't notice your comment. If you wish I'll delete my answer so that you can write yours.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni It's ok, I don't mind.  Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
def revert_morse_code_dictionary(text):
     return ''.join(morse_code_reverse.get(i) for i in text.split())
```

your first action is splitting the input string, so that you have

```
["-.-.", ".- -.", "-.--"...]
```

All spaces are removed by the `split` action. But all the elements in your dictionary contain a space in the end. For example

```
"C": "-.- ."
```

will not match the first item `-.-.`. Since the latter won't match any key, `None` will be returned by `get()`.